# How to approximate a number in R

Tags: r

In math, we can approximate a number such this:

Suppose we have `x` and `y` with these values:

`x = 0.35`

and

`y=0.67`

Then the approximate of `x` and `y` are,  `x=0.4` and `y=0.7`.

I would like to know how to do this in r.

`round` function seems to be unable to deal with this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With round :

```
x <- 0.35
round(x,digits=1)
# [1] 0.4
```

Answer (score 0):

The function round it works good, the way you need to use it is that you need to put the digits like:

```
x <- 0.34
round(x, digits = 1)
# [1] 0.3
x <- 0.37
round(x, digits = 1)
# [1] 0.4
```